# How to itemize/edit/delete results returned from a custom filter

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

Here is my filter:

```
@register.filter
def filter_by_user(queryset, user):
    """Filter the queryset by (currently logged in) user"""
    return queryset.filter(accountowner=user)
```

Here is my template:

```
<td>{{ object_list.all|filter_by_user:user|safeseq|join:". " }}</td>
```

Here is the output:

```
ACB test 5.0 55.0. ACB test 14.0 144.0
```

Here is what I d rather have

```
1. ACB test 5.0 55.0 Edit Delete

2. ACB test 14.0 144.0 Edit Delete
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`unordered_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/templates/builtins/#unordered-list) rather than `join` - despite the name, if you wrap it in `<ol>...</ol>` tags, it'll be an ordered list.

However, you should really be doing this in the view.

**Edit**

Actually, here's a better solution:

```
<ol>
{% for obj in object_list.all|filter_by_user:user %}
    <li>{{ obj }} <a href="{% url edit_object obj.id %}">Edit</a> <a href="{% url delete_object obj.id %}"Delete</a></li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Of course, this relies on you having `edit_object` and `delete_object` urls in your urlconf.

Answer (score 0):

Well, then you would need to save the result in a variable, and iterate through it, building your links. Don't hardcode the links in the filter.